# Now that Ruby has numbered block arguments are there any technical reasons why the use of symbol to proc would be still preferred?

Tags: ruby

**Updated title of the question to reflect was I was asking in content**

I did not and do not intend this to be an opinion based question,  I really want to know if there is some performance difference or memory usage difference that I should consider.  The idiom of using "symbol to proc" may remain, I just want to know if there is a technical advantage to using it.

---

Before Ruby 2.7 the use of "symbol to proc" was the preferred way to handle single method calls in blocks.

For example I think this is preferred:

```
["1", "2", "3"].map(&:to_i)
```

over this:

```
["1", "2", "3"].map {|i| i.to_i}
```

But since the introduction of numbered block arguments in Ruby 2.7 I have begun using this:

```
["1", "2", "3"].map {_1.to_i}
```

Its just as concise but also seems more consistent all the other cases were a block is needed.

Are there any reasons, other than backwards compatibility, such as performance, to chose one over the other?

Comment: Cool, I didn't even know about the numbered block arguments. Just one more big improvement I completely slept through.

Comment: I personally find the first version more readable. You could obviously replace the array creation with `%w[1 2 3].map`

Comment: While this question is purely opinion based, in my opinion `Symbol#to_proc` is a very well known ruby idiom and would be received much better than numbered block arguments (which I have only used for golf and tongue in cheek comments). Ruby prides itself on communicative variables and arguments and I personally find `_1`,`_2`, etc. to be lacking in this context as they feel very `for` loopish (as in `for i in x`) again purely my opinion.

Comment: This definitely opinion, but I feel like the first version works best if you have to chain another method call after it. `{ ... }.method` is perfectly valid, but has always felt awkward to me.

Comment: I did not intend this to be opinion based,  was looking for technical reasons.  I updated the question to try and resolve that issue.  If folks still feel it is opinion based I will not have any hard feeling if it remains closed.

Comment: There is no technical or performance benefit one way or the other to my knowledge or based on basic testing. So I think this should stay closed as it appears to be a stylistic preference.

Comment: @nPn : Do you happen to know where the _numbered block argument_ feature is described and when it was introduced? Google does not reveal anything useful for me, and my Ruby 2.6.4 does not know it yet.

Comment: @user1934428 Introduced in 2.7 [Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Proc.html#class-Proc-label-Numbered+parameters)